# How to make multiple lists in Navigation Drawer in Android

Tags: android, xml, listview, navigation-drawer, android-adapter

I am making an app, which has a navigation drawer. I want the navigation drawer to have different categories, but each category will have different adapters. Because of the unique adapters for each one, I canceled out the choice of making a single list with different headers. Can someone please help me make a navigation drawer with different lists in it? Thanks in advance!

[Google Play Navigation Drawer](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-LwVMJ9UhTvI/UpVP118oI6I/AAAAAAAAAD8/7N-TlJlkPdQ/s400/ssGoogleApps.jpg)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The closest shot is to use `Fragment`s to populate different sections in your `NavigationDrawer`.

The main idea is to make each of your sections in the drawer as a `Fragment` each with their own layouts and adapters and then push them into your drawer.

Of course explaining how to actually do this from A to Z would be inefficient. Head over to this awesome tutorial [here](http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should Use Expandable ListView as [give here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)